# Функции записи и чтения не более 32 бит в массиве байт произвольного размера на Си, есть более эффективный вариант?

Tags: c

Массив произвольного размера, сдвиг задаётся в битах относительно начала массива, ширина записываемого или читаемого поля также задаётся в битах, поле может перекрывать до 5 байт в массиве, адрес массива не обязательно выровнен по границе слова, поэтому в силу ограничения некоторых архитектур процессоров к нему возможен только побайтовый доступ.

Функция записи бит

```c
void set_bits(uint8_t* bit_field, size_t bit_field_size, uint32_t val, size_t pos, size_t size)
{
    if (size > sizeof(val) * 8)
    {
        size = (sizeof(val) * 8);
    }
    if (pos + size > bit_field_size * 8)
    {
        size = (bit_field_size * 8) - pos;
    }
    
    size_t bit_pos = pos % 8;
    size_t byte_pos = pos / 8;
    size_t shift;
    size_t s;
    if (bit_pos > 0)
    {
        s = (size + bit_pos > 8) ? 8 - bit_pos : size;
        uint8_t mask = (0xFFu >> (8 - s)) << bit_pos;
        uint8_t b_val = bit_field[byte_pos];
        bit_field[byte_pos] = (b_val & ~mask) | ((val << bit_pos) & mask);
        if (size == s)
        {
            return;
        }
        size -= s;
        pos += s;
        shift = s;
    }
    else
    {
        shift = 0;
    }
    
    s = size - (size % 8);
    byte_pos = pos / 8;
    switch (s)
    {
    case 32:
    {
        uint32_t v = val >> shift;
        bit_field[byte_pos] = v;
        bit_field[byte_pos + 1] = v >> 8;
        bit_field[byte_pos + 2] = v >> 16;
        bit_field[byte_pos + 3] = v >> 24;
        return;
    }
    case 24:
    {
        uint32_t v = val >> shift;
        bit_field[byte_pos] = v;
        bit_field[byte_pos + 1] = v >> 8;
        bit_field[byte_pos + 2] = v >> 16;
        break;
    }
    case 16:
    {
        uint32_t v = val >> shift;
        bit_field[byte_pos] = v;
        bit_field[byte_pos + 1] = v >> 8;
        break;
    }
    case 8:
        bit_field[byte_pos] = val >> shift;
        break;
    }
    if (size == s)
    {
        return;
    }
    size -= s;
    pos += s;
    shift += s;
    
    byte_pos = pos / 8;
    uint8_t mask = (0xFFu >> (8 - size));
    uint8_t b_val = bit_field[byte_pos];
    bit_field[byte_pos] = (b_val & ~mask) | ((val >> shift) & mask);
}
```

Функция чтения бит

```c
uint32_t get_bits(uint8_t* bit_field, size_t bit_field_size, size_t pos, size_t size)
{
    uint32_t val;
    if (size > sizeof(val) * 8)
    {
        size = (sizeof(val) * 8);
    }
    if (pos + size > bit_field_size * 8)
    {
        size = (bit_field_size * 8) - pos;
    }
    
    size_t bit_pos = pos % 8;
    size_t byte_pos = pos / 8;
    size_t shift;
    size_t s;
    if (bit_pos > 0)
    {
        s = (size + bit_pos > 8) ? 8 - bit_pos : size;
        val = bit_field[byte_pos] >> bit_pos;
        if (size == s)
        {
            return val;
        }
        size -= s;
        pos += s;
        shift = s;
    }
    else
    {
        val = 0;
        shift = 0;
    }
    
    s = size - (size % 8);
    byte_pos = pos / 8;
    switch (s)
    {
    case 32:
    {
        uint32_t v = bit_field[byte_pos];
        v |= bit_field[byte_pos + 1] << 8;
        v |= bit_field[byte_pos + 2] << 16;
        v |= bit_field[byte_pos + 3] << 24;
        val |= v << shift;
        return val;
    }
    case 24:
    {
        uint32_t v = bit_field[byte_pos];
        v |= bit_field[byte_pos + 1] << 8;
        v |= bit_field[byte_pos + 2] << 16;
        val |= v << shift;
        break;
    }
    case 16:
    {
        uint32_t v = bit_field[byte_pos];
        v |= bit_field[byte_pos + 1] << 8;
        val |= v << shift;
        break;
    }
    case 8:
        val |= bit_field[byte_pos] << shift;
        break;
    }
    if (size == s)
    {
        return val;
    }
    size -= s;
    pos += s;
    shift += s;

    byte_pos = pos / 8;
    val |= bit_field[byte_pos] << shift;
    return val;
}
```

Программа проверки функций

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef union
{
    uint8_t b[32];
    uint32_t v[8];
} data_t;

int main()
{
    data_t data = {0};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    {
        set_bits(data.b, sizeof(data), 0x3FF, i, 10);
        uint32_t r = get_bits(data.b, sizeof(data), i, 10);
        printf("%2d 0x%.8x 0x%.8x 0x%.8x\n", (int)i, data.v[1], data.v[0], r);
        set_bits(data.b, sizeof(data), 0, i, 10);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уберите цикл, читайте сразу до 5 байт, делайте сдвиг и сброс старших битов.

Comment: @user7860670 не совсем понятно, если не трудно, напишите код, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, эффективней ли этот код (да и короче или нет), но я выбросил циклы
(и для краткости упростил проверку аргументов).

```
// get/set any bitfield up to 32 bits
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef uint64_t u64;

u32
get_bfield (uint8_t *data, u32 dsize_bytes, u32 pos, u32 width)
{
  if (!width || width > 32 || (pos + width) > dsize_bytes * CHAR_BIT)
    return 0;

  int w = width;
  u32 mask = width == 32 ? -1 : (1 << width) - 1;
  u32 d_pos = pos / CHAR_BIT;
  u32 d_ofs = pos % CHAR_BIT;
  u32 r = data[d_pos] >> d_ofs; // result low bits
  u32 shft = CHAR_BIT - d_ofs;

  u32 x = 0;
  do {
    if ((w -= shft) <= 0) break;
    x = data[d_pos + 1];
    if ((w -= CHAR_BIT) <= 0) break;
    x |= data[d_pos + 2] << CHAR_BIT;
    if ((w -= CHAR_BIT) <= 0) break;
    x |= data[d_pos + 3] << (2 * CHAR_BIT);
    if ((w -= CHAR_BIT) <= 0) break;
    x |= data[d_pos + 4] << (3 * CHAR_BIT);
  } while (0);
  r |= (x << shft);

  return r & mask;
}

// Returns 0 if OK
int
set_bfield (uint8_t *data, u32 dsize_bytes, u32 pos, u32 width, u32 value)
{
  if (!width || width > 32 || (pos + width) > dsize_bytes * CHAR_BIT)
    return -1;

  int w = width;
  u32 d_pos = pos / CHAR_BIT;
  u32 d_ofs = pos % CHAR_BIT;
  u32 low = CHAR_BIT - d_ofs; // number of high bits in low data byte

  // write low bits
  u32 d = data[d_pos];
  u32 d_mask;
  u32 vl; // number of bits in value, that set to low data byte
  if (low >= w) // all to low byte
    d_mask = ((1 << (vl = w)) - 1) << d_ofs;
  else
    d_mask = ((1 << (vl = low)) - 1) << d_ofs;

  d &= ~d_mask;
  u32 v = value & ((1 << vl) - 1);
  data[d_pos++] = d | (v << d_ofs);
  value >>= vl;
  
  do {
    if ((w -= vl) < CHAR_BIT) break;
    data[d_pos++] = value; value >>= CHAR_BIT;
    if ((w -= CHAR_BIT) < CHAR_BIT) break;
    data[d_pos++] = value; value >>= CHAR_BIT;
    if ((w -= CHAR_BIT) < CHAR_BIT) break;
    data[d_pos++] = value; value >>= CHAR_BIT;
    w -= CHAR_BIT;
  } while (0);

  // write high bits
  if (w > 0) {
    d = data[d_pos];
    d_mask = ((1 << w) - 1);
    d &= ~d_mask;
    d |= (value & d_mask);
    data[d_pos] = d;
  }

  return 0;
}



int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  u64 d = 0x974c86fd5ae8ULL;

  u64 ds = 0;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    printf("%d", get_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 4, i, 1));
  puts("\n pos 7 w 17");
  u32 r = get_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 4, 7, 17);
  for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++)
    printf("%d", (r >> i) & 1);
  puts("\n pos 0 w 32");
  r = get_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 4, 0, 32);
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    printf("%d", (r >> i) & 1);
  puts("\n pos 6 w 21");
  r = get_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 8, 6, 21);
  for (int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    printf("%d", (r >> i) & 1);  
  puts("\n pos 5 w 27");
  r = get_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 4, 5, 27);
  for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    printf("%d", (r >> i) & 1);
  puts("\n cross bound pos 30 w 10");
  r = get_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 8, 30, 10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    printf("%d", (r >> i) & 1);
  puts("\n pos 32 w 16");
  r = get_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 8, 32, 16);
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%d", (r >> i) & 1);
  puts("\n\n setbits\n\n");

  printf("set = %d\n", set_bfield((uint8_t *)&d, 8, 2, 3, 0x5));
  printf("bitset = 0x%lx\n", d);

  printf("set -1 to 0x%lx  w 31 pos 12\n", ds);
  int rc = set_bfield((uint8_t *)&ds, 8, 11, 31, -1);
  printf("set = %d bitset = 0x%lx\n", rc, ds);

  printf("set b'11 to 0x%lx  w 2 pos 7\n", ds);
  rc = set_bfield((uint8_t *)&ds, 8, 7, 2, -1);
  printf("set = %d bitset = 0x%lx\n", rc, ds);

  puts("\n\n pos 7 w 32\n\n");
  r = get_bfield((uint8_t *)&ds, 8, 7, 32);
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    printf("%d", (r >> i) & 1);
  puts("\nEnd");
  
}
```

А вообще, если вы уверены, что выход за границы массива с данными по чтению не приведет к падению программы, то эффективней было бы (особенно при чтении поля), после обработки первого байта заполнять 32-бит переменную 4-мя байтами и работать с ней.

Comment: Спасибо, необычное использование цикла

Comment: Да, признаюсь, конформизм... Слишком много людей не воспринимают очевидный `goto ...`

Comment: Переписал функции с учётом решений из вашего кода

Comment: Оптимальный код не всегда получается кратким

Answer (score 0):

Минимальный рабочий пример для установки битов, чтение битов можно сделать аналогично.

```
int set_bits(uint32_t* bit_field, int bit_field_size
            ,uint32_t val, int pos, int size)
{
    uint32_t cur_field;
    uint32_t cur_pos;
    uint32_t cur_val;
    uint32_t mask;
    
    if (bit_field == NULL)
        return -1;
    if ((pos + size) > bit_field_size)
        return -1;
     
    bit_field += (pos/32);    
    cur_field = *bit_field;
     
    mask = (~0u) << (32-size);
    cur_val = (val & mask);
    cur_pos = pos - ((pos/32)*32);
    cur_val >>= cur_pos;
    mask = ~(mask>>cur_pos);
    cur_field &= mask;
    cur_field |= cur_val;
    *bit_field = cur_field;
      
    if ((32 - cur_pos) < size) {
        size = 32 - cur_pos;
        ++bit_field;
        cur_field = *bit_field;
        mask = (~0u) << (32 - size);
        cur_val = val << (32 - cur_pos);
        cur_val &= mask;  
        mask = ~mask;
        cur_field &= mask;
        cur_field |= cur_val;
        *bit_field = cur_field;
     }
     return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо за вариант, у вас рассматривается массив 32 разрядных чисел, в задаче возможно только побайтовое обращение массиву в силу ограничения архитектуры процессора.

Answer (score 0):

По чтению можно сделать так
( все проверки опущены )

```
uint32_t get_bits(uint8_t *bit_field, size_t bit_field_size, size_t pos, size_t size)
{
  uint64_t res;
  //res = *(uint64_t *)(bit_field + pos / 8); // чтение за границам массива - может не падать
  memcpy(&res,&bit_field[(pos/8)],1+size/8);
  res <<= (64 - (pos%8 + size));  // очистка старших бит
  res >>= (64 - size);            // старшие биты заполнены нулями, возврат к началу.
  return (uint32_t)res;
}
```

по записи ( это возможно не самый быстрый вариант )

```
static inline void set_bit(uint8_t *bit_field, int pos, int bit)
{
  uint8_t bits = 1 << pos % 8;
  bit_field[pos / 8] = bit ? bit_field[pos / 8] | bits : bit_field[pos / 8] & ~bits;
}
/* - это если совсем не спешить
void set_bits(uint8_t *bit_field, int bit_field_size, uint32_t val, int pos, int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      set_bit(bit_field,pos+i,(val>>i)&0x1);
    }
}
*/
void set_bits(uint8_t *bit_field, int bit_field_size, uint32_t val, int pos, int size)
{
  uint32_t tmp = val;
  if( pos % 8)  tmp = val >> 8-pos % 8 ;
  uint8_t *btmpp = &tmp;
  uint8_t end = size < 8 ? 1 : 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size;i++)
  {
    if ((pos + i) % 8 || end )
    {
      set_bit(bit_field, pos + i, (val >> i) & 0x1);
    }
    else 
    {
      bit_field[(pos + i) / 8] = btmpp[i / 8];
      i += 7;
      if (i + 8 >= size) end++;
    }
  }
}
```